# How to center entire iFrameset?

Tags: html, css, iframe

How can I center the whole iframeset??

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<frameset rows="100,*" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
  <frame name="topNav" src="banner.php">
<frameset cols="200,*" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame name="menu" src="menu.php" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize>
    <frame name="content" src="dashboard.php" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize>

</frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

I tried `<div>` and applying `text-align:center;` But It didnt work? !

Comment: A `frame` is **not** the same as an `iframe`. You are using frames / frameset which are [obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#frames) in HTML5 so please stop using them.

Comment: What exactly is the reason you want to use frames? I'm quite sure it isn't necessary, and it is strongly advised against to use frames altogether...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your frameset tags with these,

```
<frameset class="center" rows="100,*" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
<frameset class="center" cols="200,*" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
```

Addthese css codes for the page

```
.center
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:70%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are either going to have to create a frame on the left and right sides, or just create an `iframe` and avoid the whole issue (better option). `frameset` is obsolete so you should avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the width of the div and apply:

```
margin:auto;
```

or

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

[Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Ju8J9/)

Additionally, please avoid using frameset in the future! It is obsolete in HTML5.

Cheers!